# where to find the GSP code in JAVA in WEKA or another API?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, weka

Looking for the Generalised sequential pattern algorithm code in JAVA.

I saw earlier posts regarding this and WEKA was mentioned. After using the WEKA API I see that this algorithm doesn't show in WEKA.Associations

Is it because of the version?

there is a WEKA.associator.generalisedsequentialpattern which existed

http://weka.wikispaces.com/GeneralizedSequentialPatterns

Could some one tell me how to find the GSP algorithm JAVA code in WEKA or in another place?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Do you want a pointer to the source code of the GSP? Or do you want to know why it doesn't show up in your setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. In the older releases of WEKA around the period 2007 the GSP algorithm is implemented. In the newer versions it's removed primarily cause it's an old and inefficient compared to the newer algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Java source code of **GSP, PrefixSpan, SPAM, SPADE, BIDE, Clasp, CloSpan** and many other sequential pattern mining algorithms in the Sequential Pattern Mining Framework (SPMF), which is a specialized Java software/library offering more than 80 algorithms for pattern mining:

http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/

Answer (score 0):

weka removed some algorithms to packages in latest versions. As you can see from below image, this algorithm ,GeneralizedSequentialPatterns, is in the package list. Install it using package manager.

[image]